# NullPointerException is thrown in Youtube data api v3

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am using Youtube data api v3 in my app. I want to implement `subscriptions.insert` method in it, but my code thorws a NullPointerException. Below is my code

```
public class SubscribeActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity {

    Button play;
    private static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "My Api Key";
    private static final Collection<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl");

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Youtube Promotion";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    public static Credential authorize(final NetHttpTransport httpTransport) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"));
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, clientSecretReader);

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .build();
        Credential credential =
                new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        return credential;
    }

    public static YouTube getService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Credential credential = authorize(httpTransport);
        return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    Subscription response;
    YouTube youtubeService;
    Subscription subscription;
    SubscriptionSnippet snippet;
    ResourceId resourceId;
    YouTube.Subscriptions.Insert request;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subscribe);

        play = findViewById(R.id.youtubePlay);
     

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try{

                 
                        youtubeService = getService();
                    

                    // Define the Subscription object, which will be uploaded as the request body.
                     subscription = new Subscription();

                    // Add the snippet object property to the Subscription object.
                     snippet = new SubscriptionSnippet();
                     resourceId = new ResourceId();
                    resourceId.setChannelId("UCFCGruiJ_THqlW-5kYEcrJg");
                    resourceId.setKind("youtube#channel");
                    snippet.setResourceId(resourceId);
                    subscription.setSnippet(snippet);

                    // Define and execute the API request
                    request = youtubeService.subscriptions()
                            .insert("snippet", subscription);
                    response = request.execute();
                    System.out.println(response);
                    Log.d("TAG", "getYoutubeChannel: " + response);
                }catch (IOException e){
                    Log.d("TAG", "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
                    Log.d("TAG", "General: " + e.getMessage());
                }


            }
        });
```

**Exception is thrown in these lines**

```
Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"));
 Credential credential = authorize(httpTransport);
 youtubeService = getService();
```

Here is the logcat

```
2022-06-23 15:38:07.231 14969-14969/com.cigrastudio.youtubepromotion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cigrastudio.youtubepromotion, PID: 14969
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at com.cigrastudio.youtubepromotion.SubscribeActivity.authorize(SubscribeActivity.java:51)
    at com.cigrastudio.youtubepromotion.SubscribeActivity.getService(SubscribeActivity.java:65)
    at com.cigrastudio.youtubepromotion.SubscribeActivity$2.onClick(SubscribeActivity.java:103)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
    at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Note: I have generated an API Key in the cloud console for this project and have put `client_secrets.json` in app/src forlder. Please pardon if I have made any blunder. Thank You

**Update 1**
I have made the following changes

```
 private static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "My Api Key";
    private static final Collection<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl");
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRETS= "client_secrets.json";

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Youtube Promotion";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();


    public  Credential authorize(final NetHttpTransport httpTransport) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.


        FileReader clientSecretReader = (FileReader) new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(CLIENT_SECRETS));
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, clientSecretReader);
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .build();
        credential =
                new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        return credential;
    }


    public  YouTube getService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Credential credential = authorize(httpTransport);
        return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    Subscription response;
    YouTube youtubeService;
    Subscription subscription;
    SubscriptionSnippet snippet;
    ResourceId resourceId;
    YouTube.Subscriptions.Insert request;

    public static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY = ".oauth-credentials";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subscribe);

        play = findViewById(R.id.youtubePlay);
        youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtubePlayerView);

        youtubeService = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();

        onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo("vwpJQTRj7tU");
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        };
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, onInitializedListener );

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try{
                        youtubeService = getService();
                    // Define the Subscription object, which will be uploaded as the request body.
                     subscription = new Subscription();

                    // Add the snippet object property to the Subscription object.
                     snippet = new SubscriptionSnippet();
                     resourceId = new ResourceId();
                    resourceId.setChannelId("UCFCGruiJ_THqlW-5kYEcrJg");
                    resourceId.setKind("youtube#channel");
                    snippet.setResourceId(resourceId);
                    subscription.setSnippet(snippet);

                    // Define and execute the API request
                    request = youtubeService.subscriptions()
                            .insert("snippet", subscription);
                    response = request.execute();
                    System.out.println(response);
                    Log.d("TAG", "getYoutubeChannel: " + response);
                }catch (IOException e){
                    Log.d("TAG", "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
                    Log.d("TAG", "General: " + e.getMessage());
                }


            }
        });
```

This code throws `IOException: client_secrets.json`

[image: Location of client_secrets.json file]

Comment: wrong condition  if (youtubeService != null){
                        youtubeService = getService();
                    }

Comment: if it was not null then why are you assigning ?

Comment: Still open ?,  look at martin's answer he was explaining the same what I did, putting that file in resource or assets.

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki nothing is working.

Comment: Update the latest error that you have.

Comment: IOException: client_secrets.json

Comment: I am able to read JSON files from assets.

Comment: I don't know why my app can't read the file

Comment: can you post screenshot that shows location of client_secrets.json ?

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki I have attached the screenshot. Please check

Comment: It was in resources put that file in the assets

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 3**
Note: I have generated an API Key in the cloud console for this project and have put client_secrets.json in app/src forlder.

Currently, your file is in the resource folder, So move that file into the [**assets**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/assets-folder-in-android/#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20To%20create%20an,Keep%20all%20the%20settings%20default.) folder, and apply the below functions.

**Edit 2**

as you mentioned now error was changed to the authorize,
you have to put your json file in asset so you can easily read that file.
**InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("client_secrets.json"))**

```
public Credential authorize(final NetHttpTransport httpTransport) throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("client_secrets.json"));
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, clientSecretReader);

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                    .build();
    Credential credential =
            new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    return credential;
}
```

**getService() Function Should me non-static**

```
 public YouTube getService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Credential credential = authorize(httpTransport);
        return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }
```

Wrong condition

```
if (youtubeService != null) {
    youtubeService = getService();
}
```

The above condition reinitialize youtubeService object if its not null, means if its null then it will do nothing.

This condition should be

```
if (youtubeService == null) {
    youtubeService = getService();
}
```

Comment: I mistakenly wrote that condition by removing the condition it's still not working. Please check my question again.

Comment: not the error was changed, it was in the authorize function

Comment: @GumNaam where did you put your credentials.json file ?

Comment: I have placed in app\src\main\res folder

Comment: @GumNaam put that in asset folder, and use asset manager

Comment: getAssets() showing error as authorize is static

Comment: @GumNaam then make it non static please

Comment: Making it non static generate error in autorize(httpTransport), as it needs a static method

Comment: @GumNaam getService should be non static also

Comment: No, After making the methods non static I am getting this error IOException: /client_secrets.json

Comment: I am sure the problem is with the file. I have placed it in app>src>main>assests

Comment: @GumNaam remove the /

Comment: I have already did that and it shows this error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer;

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that the problem stems from this line:

```
new InputStreamReader(Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"));
```

Passing an actual `InputStream` might evetually help; or at least check for it:

```
if (Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json") == null) {
    throw new IOException();
}
```

`Credential` should be initialized with that JSON file / or contents.
Not getting a handle to the `InputStreamReader` and not reading `BufferedInputStream` will not result in a valid `Credential`.

The default location for file `client_secret.json` would be:

```
src/main/resources/client_secret.json
```

---

It seems as if you try to run common Java on Android, which is quite unlikely to succeed.
On Android this would be `requireContext().getResources()` with `R.raw.client_secret`:

```
src/main/res/raw/client_secret.json
```